# texlive-pstricks-doc unable to install on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: updates, 15.04, texlive

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 this past weekend, and everything installed perfectly, with the exception of `texlive-pstricks-doc`. It gave me an error when the upgrade finished.

Since then, I've tried to manually update the package, and this is my output from the terminal.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  texlive-pstricks-doc
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/85.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 9,585 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 275255 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-pstricks-doc_2014.20141024-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-pstricks-doc (2014.20141024-1) over (2014.20140717-1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-pstricks-doc_2014.20141024-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add-doc.dat.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add-doc.dat.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for tex-common (5.03) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-pstricks-doc_2014.20141024-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: File a bug.  This is something that needs fixed at the developer level, not here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. I thought it might be something related to my set up, which is why I asked here. I'll file it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after checking a couple of things, I ran `sudo apt-get clean`, then ran the update again. This time, it downloaded a new copy of `texlive-pstricks-doc`, and installed it without issue. Turns out, it was just a broken download.